# How can I expand a setting or variable in a vim regular expression?

Tags: regex, vim

I have a regular expression, `^ \{3,}/`, and want to use the value of a setting or variable in place of the `3`.  Here's the context:

```
match LeadingSpaces /^ \{3,}/
highlight LeadingSpaces ctermbg=red guibg=red
```

I'd like to use the value of `tabstop` in place of 3.  Alternatively, I could set a new variable to be used.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the following instead of `match LeadingSpaces /^ \{3,}/`:

```
execute 'match LeadingSpaces /^ \{'.&tabstop.',}/'
```

Comment: Thanks.  This works.  Is there a way to compile a string into a regex pattern so the setting expansion could be applied only to `'/^ \{'.&tabstop.',}/'`?

Comment: You could save the string `'/^ \{'.&tabstop.',}/'` to a variable and then do something like `execute 'match LeadingSpaces '.regex`.