# vimscript syntax highlighting: highlight longlines greater than &textwidth set value

Tags: regex, unix, vim

I want to highlight lines that are longer than the set textwidth so that it is dynamic for different filetypes. I have the following:

```
autocmd BufEnter * highlight OverLength ctermbg=darkgrey guibg=#592929  
autocmd FileType * execute 'match OverLength /%\{'.&textwidth.',}v.*/'
```

This code doesn't seem to activate the highlighting, however, the following does work:

```
autocmd BufEnter * highlight OverLength ctermbg=darkgrey guibg=#592929  
autocmd BufEnter * match OverLength /\%>90v.\+*/
```

I have tried excluding the execute statement and adding the backslashes accordingly but I still cannot seem to get this to work. Also, I think using the execute statement makes this code cleaner. I would appreciate it if someone could explain to me what I am doing incorrectly.

I have referenced the following examples in pursuit of the answer:

[highlight long lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395114/vim-syntax-coloring-how-do-i-highlight-long-lines-only)

[expand a variable in regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606485/how-can-i-expand-a-setting-or-variable-in-a-vim-regular-expression)

If there is a more portable and cleaner way to go about this then please let me know. I am trying to learn as much as possible.

---

**ANSWER**:
What I ended up doing is utilizing vim's vim/after/ftplugin folder hierarchy and adding: 
`set textwidth=100`
`let &colorcolumn=join(range(&textwidth+1,999),",")`
to each filetype.vim file e.g. markdown.vim, java.vim, vim.vim

And for help.vim and man.vim files I didn't want colorcolumn highlighting so I changed the textwidth in those files to `999`. By doing this vim was able to distinguish between different file types when they were open in the same session.

Comment: `execute 'match OverLength /\%>'.&textwidth.'v.*/'`

Comment: What autocmd-event did you call with this because it still isn't highlighting after the specified textwidth for different filetypes.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is utilizing vim's vim/after/ftplugin folder hierarchy and adding: 
`set textwidth=100`
`let &colorcolumn=join(range(&textwidth+1,999),",")`
to each filetype.vim file e.g. markdown.vim, java.vim, vim.vim

And for help.vim and man.vim files I didn't want colorcolumn highlighting so I changed the textwidth in those files to `999`. By doing this vim was able to distinguish between different file types when they were open in the same session.

– user2904000